# Importing CSV into MySql workbench table with different columns

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have several CSV files in one folder with the same structure and would like to import it to a Database for further analysis.

The CSV columns are the following:

**Company_Code , Company_Name , Year , Account_number  , Account_Description, Value**

My intention is to use this CSV to populate 3 tables in my DB in MySQL Workbench. This tables are responsible for organizing:

- company_data: id, code and name.
- Accounts: id, account number and account description.
- Values: companyID, accountID, year and value.

[image: table diagramm]

I want to always keep the relationship between company values and account, but in a way that makes easier queries and analysis.

I have tried python but i can't figure out how to attach foreign keys. I don't know if its better to import to a temporary table and then populate each table, directly in MySQL workbench

Edit:
For my python approach i was trying to retrive data from an XML file that has the same information but it started getting to techinical because I would need to implement several valdations that with the CSV are not necessary.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET;
import csv
import mysql.connector;

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "########",
    database = "cvmsanepar"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor();
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE CVM (conta VARCHAR(255), descricao VARCHAR(255), valor1 INTEGER(10), valor2 INTEGER(10), valor3 INTEGER(10))");


dfpTree = ET.parse("InfoFinaDFin.xml");
dfpRoot = dfpTree.getroot(); 

conta1 = []; #codigo CVM do plano de contas (accounts)
descricao = []; #descrição do plano de conta (account description)
valor1 = []; #valor ano do documento (value year 1)
valor2 = []; #valor ano anterior (value year 2)
valor3 = []; #valor ano anterior do anterior (value year 3)


for numeroDeConta in dfpRoot.iter('NumeroConta'):
    conta1.append(numeroDeConta.text);

for descricaoConta in dfpRoot.iter('DescricaoConta1'):
    descricao.append(descricaoConta.text);


for valor in dfpRoot.findall('InfoFinaDFin'):
    valor1.append(valor.find('ValorConta1').text);
    valor2.append(valor.find('ValorConta2').text);
    valor3.append(valor.find('ValorConta3').text);


def merge(conta1,descricao,valor1,valor2,valor3):
    mergedList = [(conta1[i], descricao[i], valor1[i], valor2[i], valor3[i]) for i in range(0, len(conta1))]
    return mergedList

sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO CVM (conta, descricao, valor1, valor2, valor3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, merge(conta1,descricao,valor1,valor2,valor3));
mydb.commit();
```

Comment: _Small Point_ Workbench is not a database, its a tool written to make playing with a MySQL Database easier

Comment: If you show your Python code someone will most likely give you a hand with it

Comment: remove extraneous excuse/help/thanks cruft as per SO guidelines.